# Super (Win button) + mouse scrolling won't switch desktop/workspace

Tags: shortcut-keys, xorg, workspaces, shortcuts, wayland

When I was on wayland I used to switch desktop/workspaces by pressing the Super key and by scrolling with the mouse wheel. How to enable that behaviour in x11? Combinations like Super + Alt left + Left/Right or Super + ALT Tab are still working.